# asynchronous xml request doesn't return

Tags: javascript, xml, servlets, asynchronous, request

So I'm trying to rewrite a synchronous xml request into an asynchronous xml request. I've very new to this, so please forgive me if the error is really stupid.

Anyways, this is currently what I've got.

```
var getEmployeeData = function(section, question, column){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", Data.contextPath + "/main/?action=get-employee-list&section=" +section+ "&question=" +question+ "&column=" +column, true)
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                if (employeeDataDone) {
                    if (xhr.responseText==("\r\n")) {
                        employeeList = null;
                        employeeInverseList = null;
                    } else {
                        employeeList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)[0];
                        employeeInverseList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)[1];
                    }
                }
            } else {
              console.error(xhr.statusText);
            }
          }
    }.bind(this);
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(xhr.statusText);
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}.bind(this);
```

Any help is appreciated, and if you need any extra information that I've neglected to include, simply ask for it.

Thanks!

Comment: why are you checking 4 and 200 inside the onload?

Comment: @epascarello I have no idea, sorry I'm super new to this. Can those be removed?

Comment: @epascarello He was using the wrong method name on the XHR object.  Using the correct method name is invoked several times throughout the life of the request in different states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be listening for the onreadystatechange event or attach a function with that name to the object.  The following should solve your issue:

```
var getEmployeeData = function(section, question, column){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", Data.contextPath + "/main/?action=get-employee-list&section=" +section+ "&question=" +question+ "&column=" +column, true)
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                if (employeeDataDone) {
                    if (xhr.responseText==("\r\n")) {
                        employeeList = null;
                        employeeInverseList = null;
                    } else {
                        employeeList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)[0];
                        employeeInverseList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)[1];
                    }
                }
            } else {
              console.error(xhr.statusText);
            }
          }
    }.bind(this);
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(xhr.statusText);
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}.bind(this);
```

Edit:
For more details I would recommend looking at the Wikipedia [entry for XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Ohh woops, I totally remember seeing that somewhere. I guess I forgot to change my onload to onreadystatechange. That's awesome, thank you Mark!

Comment: I totally find myself scratching my head over forgot API names from time to time.  As for your other response which has seems to have gotten lost in the giant bitbucket in the sky, I would invoke your data to DOM binding message in the body of your onreadystatechange method.

If you've found the answer helpful, please up-vote.  You can up-vote response too!  This rewards people who give helped you.  Additionally if an answer solves your problem you can mark it as answered, giving yourself and the person answering additional points.

Comment: Yea, I dunno what happened to my last response. How would I go about DOM binding? Also upvoted and gave you a checkmark :).

Comment: Depends on your application and what you want the resultant markup to be.  If you are using jQuery you can easily pass the markup fragments to an element via the append method; if you are using pure JS you should use the innerHTML property of the target element of an element [simplest method is document.getElementById( idAttributeValue ) ].

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. If I simply add to the element using document.getElementById(id), how does that help me when I haven't received the information back from the server yet?

Comment: You need to wait until you receive a response before you can render any content.  My recommendation is you define a function which will render the data, then call the function after you update the employeeList and employeeInverseList variables.